# Call c# class from C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli

I would like to export my c# class with c++/cli:

Here is my header(.h) file and my .cpp

```
using namespace System;
using namespace Microsoft::Kinect;
using namespace std;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

class clrPrivate;

class __declspec(dllexport) clr
{
private: clrPrivate* _private;



public: clr();
public: ~clr();


public: String^ calculate(Double* Robot_Points_Values[], CameraSpacePoint* human_point_cloud, unsigned char* bodyindexdata[]);
};
```

and my .cpp file

```
// This is the main DLL file.
#using "FULLPATH\MYDLL.dll"
#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>
#include "ClassLibrary4.h"
#include <array>
//#include "stdafx.h"


using namespace Distance_Test;
using namespace std;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices; 
using namespace Microsoft::Kinect;
using namespace System;

class clrPrivate
{
public: msclr::auto_gcroot<MINIMUM_DISTANCE^> out;
};


   clrPrivate* _private;

         clr::clr()
        {
            _private = new clrPrivate();
            _private->out = gcnew MINIMUM_DISTANCE;
        };

        String^ clr::calculate(Double* Robot_Points_Values[], CameraSpacePoint* human_point_cloud, unsigned char* bodyindexdata[])
        {


            String^ output;
        return  output = _private->out->calculate(*Robot_Points_Values, *human_point_cloud, **bodyindexdata);
            //return  output = _private->out->value_return;
        };

  clr::~clr()
{
    delete _private;
};
```

When i run debug mode  it shows me 2 errors:

1) Error C3395'clr::calculate': __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention

2)Error C2228   left of '.value_return' must have class/struct/union

i am trying 2 days now to find a solution but i have stuck.If someone could help me, i would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need __declspec(dllexport) for managed classes, as they are exported automatically unless you declare them private/internal. Just change the class signature like this:

```
public ref class clr
```

Also if you want to use this from C# you should use managed arrays in the signature of the calculate method:

```
String^ calculate(array<Double*>^ Robot_Points_Values, CameraSpacePoint* human_point_cloud, array<unsigned char*>^ bodyindexdata);
```